# mvc:resources leads to ClassCastException

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC webapp that should serve static resources.
Therefore I have the following spring configuration:

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
```

But each request to a resource leads to the same ugly ClassCastException:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.springframework.core.io.Resource
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.getResource(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:158)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:109)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:49)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.myproject.filter.SetP3PHeaderFilter.doFilter(SetP3PHeaderFilter.java:48)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.myproject.filter.SessionIdUrlFilter.disableDefaultURLEncoding(SessionIdUrlFilter.java:83)
at com.myproject.filter.SessionIdUrlFilter.avoidSessionFixation(SessionIdUrlFilter.java:53)
at com.myproject.filter.SessionIdUrlFilter.doFilter(SessionIdUrlFilter.java:42)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:185)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:151)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:269)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I tried it with version 3.1.0.RELEASE and 3.0.4.RELEASE of the spring framework and observed the exact same behavior.

Comment: posting your entire configuration xml here will be helpful... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really weird, but the problem seems to be, that I had defined a conversion service like this:

```
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <list>
           <bean    class="com.example.CustomConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Which was referenced here:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />
```

Turns out if I change the bean id to something different like f. e. `cs` it works fine. This is really strange as the same id is used in the documentation and the showcases.

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing `mvc:annotation-driven` in your configuration, that is the one which registers the property editor to transform from string to a resource, that is likely causing this error message for you.

Comment: Thx again - you brought my attention to the property editor, which led me to the solution below.